# Strange php date sum behavior

Tags: php, date, sum

Why does this sum only 4 days when using 25-Oct-13 and 5 days (as expected) when using other dates?

```
<?php
    echo date('d-M-y',(strtotime('25-Oct-13') + (432000)));
?>
```

Comment: Summer and wintertime

Comment: So, adding one more hour should fix this?

Comment: You can use `strtotime()`'s functionality for that: `25-Oct-13 + 5days`

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php for more info on comment above

Comment: Iam able to get exact 5 days added to the date as per your code

Comment: yes, it's all about the timezone. When using my European time zone it fails, so I've added this line with some random American time-zone: date_default_timezone_set('America/Adak');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on your timezone. The last Saturday of October is the end of Daylight Saving Time (DST) in some locales. Therefore the night of October 26th to 27th in 2013 may or may not contain an extra hour.

Circumvent this issue by adding actual days instead of hours:

```
$myDate = new \Datetime('2013-10-25');
$myDate->add(new \DateInterval('P5D'));
```

[This does return Oct 30th 2013](https://eval.in/184032).

[More strange stuff can happen from incorrectly assuming that days are always exactly 24 hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841333/why-is-subtracting-these-two-times-in-1927-giving-a-strange-result/6841479#6841479).

Comment: I've added this: date_default_timezone_set('America/Adak'); It works fine now. Thank you!

Comment: Changing the timezone is not a fundamental solution to your problem.

Comment: I don't understand the meaning of 'fundamental solution' but as long as it won't cause me any trouble it's ideal. It's the only operation I'm doing with those dates; no other details will be used/ added, ever.

Comment: The point of a fundamental solution is that it *will not* cause you any trouble. Changing the timezone to a region that has another DST rule is a recipe for disaster when changing other dates, or when they do introduce DST in Adak. The fundamental solution is to calculate with days, not hours, as stated in my answer.

Comment: Done it your way. Works (probably you already knew that xD).
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

$date = "2014-09-17";

echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date.' + 5 days'));